# How to locate tuples in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I apologize if this has been asked but I can't quite find it anywhere.
I have a pandas dataframe that contains color tuples, I want to find all rows that contain a certain tuple, but when I try to search for a tuple it instead searches for columns or something? I'm attaching a picture of a notebook example of what I mean

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J460v.png

Comment: Don't you want this: `df = pd.DataFrame({'color': [red, blue, red, blue]})` (note the square brackets).  Works fine with this specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

red = (255,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)

df = pd.DataFrame({'color':(red, blue, red, blue)})

>>> df.loc[df['color'] == red]
         color
0  (255, 0, 0)
2  (255, 0, 0)

>>> df.loc[df['color'] == red].index
Int64Index([0, 2], dtype='int64')
```